# Show that the operator norm $\sum$ defined as $\sum(\lbrace{x_n\rbrace}_{n=0}^\infty) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lbrace{x_n\rbrace}$ is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Suppose $\|\lbrace{x_n\rbrace}_{n=0}^\infty \|_{\text{sup}} = \text{sup}\lbrace{|x_n|\rbrace}_{n=0}^\infty $. Let $\sum$ be a linear operator from the $A \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $\sum(\lbrace{x_n\rbrace}_{n=0}^\infty) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\lbrace{x_n\rbrace}$ and $A$ is the set of absolutely convergent sequences. Show that the operator norm of $\sum$ is unbounded.

So I understand I need to show for every $m > 0$, there exists an absolutely convergent sequence such that$\frac{|\sum (x_n)|}{\|\lbrace{x_n\rbrace}\|_\text{sup}} > m $ I have no idea where to proceed with this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With absolute value signs in wrong places the question hardly makes sense. Please edit it carefully.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment because I do not have enough reputation, but try to find a sequence that sums to $m$ and is still absolutely convergent with supremum one (i.e. each term in the sequence is at most one, but the sum is $m$).

Comment: does $x_n = 1 $ count?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by this; can you be a bit more explicit?